# Replace a string in a file and overwrite the file

Tags: bash, files, text-processing

I wrote my script using the the directory `~/deleted` (it's a long script). after using `~/deleted` for the whole script. I want to let the user choose the directory by putting the path in `~/.rm.cfg`.

My file starts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

defaultpath=~/deleted

if [ -s ~/.rm.cfg ]
then
    defaultpath=$(head -1 ~/.rm.cfg)
fi
```

I need to replace every `~/deleted`  with `$defaultpath` in my script. Is there a way to do it in command line such that it saves and replaces the original file?

I can't get either perl or sed to work.

Comment: The first line defaultpath=~/deleted will be added again after all "~/deleted" strings have been replace by $defaultpath

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create a new file and then rename that to replace the old file?

Comment: `sed` should suffice. What did you try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed -i 's|~/deleted|"$defaultpath"|g' file.sh
```

Explanation:

- `-i` tells `sed` to modify the file in place.
- `s|~/deleted|"$defaultpath"|g` tells `sed` to replace `~/deleted` with `"$defaultpath"` whereever it finds it.

#### Extra feature: preserve ~/deleted on the third line

You did not ask for this but, in your example script, it would be nice to leave `~/deleted` unchanged on the third line where it is used to define `defaultpath`.  To change all instances of `~/deleted` *except* the one on the third line, use:

```
sed -i -e '3n' -e 's|~/deleted|"$defaultpath"|g' file.sh
```

This adds the single `sed` command `3n` which tells `sed` to skip the third line.

Comment: I wasn't including the quotes around $defaultpath thank you

Comment: hahha, now you're just showing off